# Scara chess robot design for 3d printing

Tags: robotic-arm, 3d-printing

I have two question regarding a Chess robot.

1. I want to build a Scara  robot that could play chess on a 37 x 37 cm chess board, but I couldn't find any design that can cover the whole chess board and an extra space to throw dead pieces, and I have no experience in editing 3d printer files, so where I could find such designs for free?
2. What is the best total length for Scara robot arm to be able to cover the whole chessboard and an extra area to throw the pieces?

Answer (score 0):

1- Grabcad is a good source for free 3D material: https://grabcad.com/library

2- The "best" total length, depends on lots of factors. You want it to be 37x37cm, ok, but that workspace will require a conscientious analysis and design of other components as well -> Mostly the arms geometry. You can check on the design of cantilever beams and static stress calculation. If your arm is too long (more than 30, 40cm), it's better to double check these kind of things before building it.